# Python collection string representation

Tags: python, collections

I am looking for some help getting from the string below

{id=1, st=20.0, al=3, ct=20.4, s=0}

To a collection in Python. Is there a simple way?

Comment: @l'mahdi this will not work because this is not standard json

Comment: @Sayse Tried it also not he needs to convert the keys to strings

Comment: Where are you getting this string from? Might be easier to fix it at the source.

Comment: use yaml to load this data

Comment: @jack - Sure, I realised that, maybe closer to a config file but isn't worth guessing what real data is at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify what can be in the collection, I assumed string keys (without spaces) and floats.

Assuming the string was in `mystring`:

```py
result = {l.split("=")[0] : float(l.split("=")[1]) for l in mystring.replace(" ", "")[1:-1].split(",")}
```

Walktrough:

- get rid of all spaces: `mystring.replace(" ", "")`
- get rid of curly braces: `mystring.replace(" ", "")[1:-1]`
- split at comas: `mystring.replace(" ", "")[1:-1].split(",")`
  Now we have a list: `['id=1', 'st=20.0', 'al=3', 'ct=20.4', 's=0']`.
  Each element will be a k-v pair, so I add a [dict comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/).
- For each list element `l`, we split at '=' -> `l.split("=")`.
- The first part will be the key as-is: `l.split("=")[0]`
- parse the second part as float: `float(l.split("=")[1])`
  Put it all together, and you get my one-liner.

I did the splitting twice, this could be removed by a bit of refactoring.

Comment: Damn you were faster than me ^^'

Comment: @jack I just paused by my laptop for 5 minutes. :D

Comment: @jack don't forget to add an alternative solution if you solved it another way

Comment: It's pretty much the same but I lost time trying it to make it a one liner like yours ^^'